# Mobile menu don't show on mobile phone only on desktop

Tags: css, mobile, menu

I created CSS mobile menu on my site and it works fine on my laptop. When i minimize browser on laptop under 680px default menu became mobile menu, but on smartphone don't work like that it stay default menu. What did I do wrong?

```css
/* CSS Document */
body{
 font-family: 'Prompt', Sans-serif;
 background-image: url(wallpaper.png);
 background-color:#ECCB6C;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 }
header{
 background-image:url(logo.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:bottom left;
 width:60%;
 height:220px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 }
nav{
 width:70%;
 height:auto;
 margin:0 auto 3px auto;
 background-image:url(hfbkg.png);
 padding:0 80px 0 80px;
 }
nav ul{
 overflow:hidden;
  padding:0;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0;
 transition:max-height 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition:max-height 0.4s;
 -ms-transition:max-height 0.4s;
 -moz-transition:max-height 0.4s;
 -o-transition:max-height 0.4s;
 }
nav ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px 7px;
 }
nav ul li:hover{
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 }
.handle {
 width:100%;
 text-align:left;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:15px 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 display:none;
 }
 
@media screen and (max-width: 680px){
 nav ul{
  max-height:0;
 }
 .showing{
  max-height:20em;
 } 
 nav ul li{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding:15px 0px;
  margin:0;
  text-align:left; 
 }
 .handle{
  display:block;
 }
 }
 
@media (max-width:680px){
 #kontakt{
  width:100%;
 }
 #iframe{
  width:100%;
 }
 }
 
section{
 width:70%;
 height:auto;
 background-image:url(textbkg.png);
 line-height:1.5em;
 font-size:1.1em;
 padding:60px 80px;
 margin:0 auto;
 clear:both;
 }
section a:link {
 color:#000000;
 }
section a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#FFAE00;
 }
section a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#000000;
 }
#textarea{
 width:350px;
 height:200px;
 padding:2px;
 margin:5px;
 }
#ime{
 width:350px;
 height:20px;
 padding:2px;
 margin:5px;
 }
#email{
 width:350px;
 height:20px;
 padding:2px;
 margin:5px;
 }
#decoupauge img{
 margin:1%;
 border: thick solid;
 with: 15px;
 color: #353439;
 padding:2px;
 }
#ukrasi img{
 margin:1%;
 border: thick solid;
 with: 15px;
 color: #353439;
 padding:2px;
 } 
#sponzori{
 margin:5%;
 align-content:center;
 }
#kontaktobr{
 width:400px;
 height:auto;
 margin:20px 0;
 padding:10px;
 float:left;
 }
#iframe{
 float:right;
 margin:20px 0;
 padding:10px;
 }
#adresa { /* pošto su iframe i kontakt obrazac u floatu u adresi ne smije biti float zato što adresa razvlači section background do footera */
 width:410px;
 height:auto;
 margin:10px;
 padding:20px;
 }
#adresa p {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0;
 }
#adresa a:link{
 color:#000000;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
#adresa a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#FFAE00;
 }
footer{
 width:70%;
 height:auto;
 margin:3px auto 0 auto;
 background-image:url(hfbkg.png);
 padding:5px 80px;
 text-align:end;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 clear:both;
 }
footer a:hover{
 color:#FBEE9A;
 } 
a{
 margin:0;
 }
a:link {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 }
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#363539;
 }
a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #363539;
 }
p{
 text-align:justify;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prompt" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
 font-family: Prompt, Sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>

<body background="wallpaper.png">

<header>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
    <a href="index.html"><li>Početna</li></a>
    <a href="terapija.html"><li>Terapije</li></a>
    <a href="galerija.html"><li>Glerija</li></a>
    <a href="donacije.html"><li>Donacije</li></a>
    <a href="linkovi.html"><li>Linkovi</li></a>
    <a href="kontakt.html"><li>Kontakt</li></a>
 </ul>
 <div class="handle">Menu</div>
 </nav>
 <section>
   <h3><strong>O nama</strong></h3>
   <p> Udruga je počela sa radom 2013. godine..</p>
    </section>
    <script>
 $('.handle').on('click', function(){
  $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
 });
 </script>

<footer>
<a>Copyright 2016</a>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define a viewport?

It needs a meta tag in the `<head>` to work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```